# Choose which partitions are able to lock with Windows 10 fast boot for dual boot

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot

I have a dual-boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed. They are on the same SSD, and I have a HDD for files and programs that I don't really need to have a fast launch time. This last has one NTFS partition.

I would like to have the fast boot setup enabled, but Windows decides to lock my HDD drive. This problem does not happen when I have the fast boot disabled.

Is there a way to tell Windows that this drive should not be locked (and saved to a consistent state if needed) whenever I choose to use the bast boot?

Answer (score 0):

You should really be thankful that the operating system are clever enough to
protect you with this unsafe setup, since otherwise you risk destroying your disk.
Fast boot and dual boot cannot both coexist.

I quote from an [Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/452574)
which is for Windows 8 but applies also to Windows 10:

> **Fast boot** in Windows 8 is a way to boot the system faster because the needed data to boot (Drivers, User session, etc..) are stored in a
>   hibernation file (`hiberfile`) and are loaded when the boot process
>   begins, saving the user between 40% and more boot time.
>
> Since Hibernation mode is a way to "freeze" whatever you were doing
>   before shutdown and loading it again when you start the computer (this
>   includes opened apps, sessions, drivers, the last office doc you were
>   editing...) it creates a problem when you want to copy stuff from
>   Ubuntu to Windows after a hibernation, or "fast boot" as it is called
>   on Windows 8 because anything that changes between hibernating and
>   booting again is lost.
>
> Basically, if you shutdown Windows 8 (hibernate mode) and then go to
>   Ubuntu and try to copy something over to Windows 8 like an mp3 file
>   (assuming Ubuntu does not throw any warnings about it being in
>   hibernation mode), when you boot Windows 8 again, the mp3 file will
>   not be there because it was not frozen during the shutdown procedure
>   you did on Windows 8 before going to Ubuntu. Since the mp3 file was
>   not there BEFORE shutting down Windows 8, it was not saved in the
>   hiberfile and thus will not be restored after you do a Fast boot to
>   load Windows.

Comment: I am aware that the fast boot act in a hibernate-like way, and it is good that the system tries to protect the integrity of the data.
Maybe I was just misinformed, but I understood that the fast boot option was like putting the drivers in a hibernate state. My thought was that it would only affect the partition that has the OS installed.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but that's exactly the problem : the other OS won't know about it.